# Is it a good idea to link to Google?

Tags: discussion

Many questions could have obviously been answered through the first, most obvious Google search that comes to mind. Also, I often get asked in the comments to provide trivial information that is easily searchable.

In those cases I like to link to Google ([like this](https://www.google.com/webhp?complete=1&hl=en#complete=1&hl=en&q=sql%20server%20scale%20out)) as a comment. It is a very time-efficient way to direct the OP to the existing information on the web. It is not being done in a mean way like LMGTFY is. I think it is a polite, helpful hint to him what he should have done.

Finding a duplicate on Stack Overflow would be too time-consuming and often not even the best possible answer.

Is this compatible with the policies of this site? Is it a good idea to do it?

Comment: I don't see a problem with it as long as you do it in a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: IMHO, It's better to also add 1 or 2 links from search result to be more clear, because without them, it is more-or-less the same as LMGTFY.

Comment: I tend to link to Wikipedia in such cases. If it's more programming-related then there *should* be a SO question that deals with the problem (which you yourself might have found via Google).

Comment: One thing to remember is that Google does customize the search results so while you may get results with good links at the top someone else may not. Also while a site may be a good resource for some people it might get to technical and hard to understand for others.

Comment: @JoeW I only link to search results if there are obvious matches. They will show up no matter what customizations are applied.

Answer (score 8):

If you give someone a reference to google, you will (hopefully) already have googled this yourself. As you suggest googling it you will also have found a few websites that will/can be useful. It wouldn't take much time to visit a few of the most promising websites just to get the links. I believe most people answering a lot of questions recognize a good source almost immediately, whereas the ones asking probably won't know what to look for.

If you know a lot about the subject and know where to look, a comment like the one below won't take much more than a minute to write.

> You'll find many good sources if you try to [google this](https://www.google.no/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=how+to+peel+a+banana), for
>   instance [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Peel-a-Banana) and [here](http://www.instructables.com/id/The-correct-way-to-peel-a-banana/).

For those who don't know, the syntax for links in comments is:

> `Check out [this link](http://www.instructables.com/id/The-correct-way-to-peel-a-banana/) to find out how to peel a banana.`

Comment: Good point. On the other hand very few articles can cover a topic to a satisfactory extent. I'd need to select probably 3+ for most cases. And they can get out of date over time. The search results are timeless. I also like to take the opportunity to teach them how to use a search engine (which is not a given - you need to a) do it and b) pick the right search terms).

Comment: @usr No, search results are not timeless. Google changes their algorithm. Sites go down. Things change. That's why we prefer that people take the time to answer questions *here*, rather than linking to another site. Just linking to search results is little better than telling someone to RTFM.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I think what he meant by timeless, is that although sites can go down, rendering specific links invalid, a link to the search page will always be useful even if the sites that are the top results today, are not there tomorrow.