# How do we handle questions that one could have found answer to just by googling?

Tags: discussion, questions, close-reasons

I often come across questions on SO, which are so simple and straight-forward. Infact just copy pasting the header of the question, one can get solution to the problem.

When I hit the close question link, I have the following options -

[image]

Though I have always seen people selecting "unclear what you're asking" option. But it's kind of not correct IMHO, I know what this guy is exactly asking but its too easy, sometimes I see people giving them links to https://lmgtfy.com and www.justfuckinggoogleit.com.

Comment: Not all bad questions are off-topic.

Comment: I never mentioned anything about off-topic. Sorry if I wasn't clear before.

Comment: What I meant to say was not all bad questions are closeable. I have a really bad habit of forgetting that not all close reasons are due to being off-topic and/or treating closeable and off-topic as interchangeable. If it's super easy there's a good chance a duplicate exists but otherwise we don't really have a close reason just for lack of research.

Comment: *LMGTFY*...oh wait...never mind.

Comment: If it is lack of research, I would downvote.. It is not a reason to close it.

Comment: prepend your google search string with `site:stackoverflow.com` and close as a duplicate of question that appears in search results. Don't forget to vote down along the way. See also: [Reviewing some awful questions is just a waste of time, can we have a “no comment” close reason for these?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261859/839601)

Comment: If you found it on google mark as a dupe and vote down.

Comment: Related: [Is it a good idea to link to Google?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253505/21960)

Comment: Related: [Show Google results before user can post a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/336128/21960)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The mere fact that a question's answer can be easily found on Google (or in the documentation, or whatever) does not mean that the question is inappropriate for Stack Overflow. If none of the close reasons fit, then you should not be voting to close the question.

To put it another way: simple, straight-forward questions *are* on-topic here, even if they're not destined to become popular. If you have an answer, please post it. Even better if you can back it up with an authoritative reference to the documentation, or some other resource with a respectable reputation found via Google. The logic here is that Stack Overflow has set a goal for itself of being a repository of expert answers to programming questions, and that includes simple questions.

The only time you can legitimate *close* these questions is if they are duplicates of a question that has already been asked on Stack Overflow. For the really obvious ones, this is probably the case, so it's usually a good idea to run a quick search before navigating away from the question.

"Too broad" is *sometimes* an option, but only if the question is—well, you know, *actually too broad*. Please don't abuse "too broad" as "too obvious". They are nearly polar opposites. Same thing with "unclear what you're asking". If you found the answer using Google, the question was almost certainly clear enough for you to understand and identify the proper search terms.

You are, of course, always welcome to *downvote* the question if you think it is "not useful" or fails to show research effort. These are explicitly given as valid downvote reasons in the arrow's tooltip.

See also:

- [Embrace the non-Googlers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/embrace-the-non-googlers)
- [How should we deal with Google questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8724/how-should-we-deal-with-google-questions)
- [Is it reasonable to downvote a question that 'could be googled' but isn't a duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262427/is-it-reasonable-to-downvote-a-question-that-could-be-googled-but-isnt-a-dupl)

Comment: Spot on. Stack overflow is great because it is repository of expert answers as opposed to having to look through numerous search results that are less likely to directly answer your question and/or have low quality answers.

Comment: I would like this answer even more if it stressed closing duplicates appropriately *before* answering.